# Match the entire row from one table with another and then return a value from table 1 in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

If I have two tables, Table 1 has the following data

```
***
CTRL Number   DATE     MEMO        DOLLAR 

1             4/4/2014  "xyz"     505050

2             4/5/2014  "fadf"      99999

3             4/6/2014   "Afdf"    59754
```

and table 2 has the following data

```
   DATE     MEMO        DOLLAR 

    4/4/2014  "xyz"     505050

    4/5/2014  "fadf"      99999

    4/6/2014   "Afdf"    59754
```

I want to match the entire row in Table 2 with the row in Table 1, and then return the Control Number in a new column in Table 2

I can't seem to figure out the index/match function to make it happen

Answer (score 0):

You may use the concatenate() to combine the values of cells in one table. as shown in the screenshot.

This formula will also produce the same result.`=IF(B2&C2=E2&F2,A2,"")` because `&` itself means concatenate.

**Note:** You can add as many cells as you like but the order/arrangement of columns should be identical.

[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eywQc.png)